# how to get a random image on 1 imageView?

Tags: android

how can I get a random image by just using 1 imageView?

here is my java code and it still does not work can someone please help me please.

```
public class Gameplay extends Activity
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gameplay);

    final int[] images = {
            R.drawable.easy1, R.drawable.easy2};

    final ImageButton shuffle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 
    shuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {        
            Random generator = new Random();

            ImageView singleImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            singleImageView.setImageResource(images[generator.nextInt(images.length - 1)]);
        }
    });     

}

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shown still have the solution for your question, your problem is how to get random images out of given array.

images[generator.nextInt(images.length - 1): this will get you random image everytime, show it on your image view.

Comment: just it on your image view?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you're asking for one ImageView to appear on screen at a time, and you'd like to only allocate a single ImageView and replace the image with a random image at some time in your app.  For that, you can simply allocate a single image view (just put one imageView in your view) and use imageview.setImageResource as follows:

```
ImageView singleImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.single_image_view)
singleImageView.setImageResource(images[generator.nextInt(images.length - 1)];
```

Comment: Yes, but what is showing and what isn't showing?  Are you getting the first image to show?  Have you checked that your button is actually registering a click and getting to the setImageResource code?

Comment: imageView has a default image right? so I'm sure that it will show no matter what haha and it doesn't have a button it should change everytime the gameplay loads right and the Imageview will get the setImageResoure only

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `generator.nextInt(images.length - 1)` is equivalent with `generator.nextInt(1)` and therefore it always returns 0, since `Random.nextInt(int)`

> returns:
>   the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and n (**exclusive**) from this random number generator's sequence

(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int))